# Old MacBook Pro 17" freezes when WiFi gets turned off

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, wifi, performance

I recently updated from Mountain Lion to Mavericks 10.9.4 on my late 2007 MacBook Pro 17". Now every time I turn off WiFi, the computer freezes within a few seconds to a few minutes. Upon reboot, the computer freezes again very quickly (sometimes at the login screen, sometimes right after getting to the desktop). I assume this happens as soon as the computer checks the WiFi state and sees that it's off.  It all happens too quickly for me to flip the WiFi back on.

I thought I was stuck (save for wiping the computer and reinstalling the OS every time this accidentally happens), but someone found a partial solution, posted on the following thread:

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5603415?start=21

The user "Ira Wolf 81" identified 4 steps which I will copy below:

1. Boot into single user mode (<kbd>command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>)
2. Make volume read-write (`mount -uw /`)
3. Edit /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/preferences.plist to change the PowerEnabled setting for the Airport Interface (usually en1) from `false` to `true`
4. Reboot

This worked for me, and I'm grateful to be able to use my computer again. But (1) it doesn't address the underlying issue of why turning off WiFi would freeze the computer, and (2) I have to manually follow these 4 steps anew every time this happens.

So I'm wondering if a script can automate Ira Wolf 81's solution.  One idea is to read and possibly edit that preferences.plist file every time the computer gets booted normally, and to do this before the OS can read that file.

Anyone want to take a crack at this?

Alternatively, if anyone knows how to fix the underlying issue, that would be cool too.

**Edit:**

In the name of science, I just intentionally turned off WiFi and waited for my computer to freeze (which it did), all the while secretly logging its actions with the Console. Here are the logs from the moment I turned off WiFi at 5:31:42 PM right up until the freeze at about 5:33 PM:

```
5:31:42.000 PM kernel: AirPort: Link Down on en1. Reason 8 (Disassociated because station leaving).
5:31:42.000 PM kernel: en1: BSSID changed to 00:1d:d2:b9:f0:10
5:31:42.000 PM kernel: 8436.409638: setDISASSOC from ATH_INTERFACE_CLASS disconnectVap
5:31:42.000 PM kernel: 8436.422991: setDISASSOCIATE ****STA SYNC DISASSOC SUCCESS  
5:31:42.000 PM kernel: 8436.423020: switchVap from 1 to 1 
5:31:42.904 PM airportd: _handleLinkEvent: WiFi is not powered. Resetting state variables.
5:31:42.000 PM kernel: flow_divert_kctl_disconnect (0): disconnecting group 1
5:31:43.990 PM configd: network changed: v4(en1-:10.0.0.16) v6(en1-:2601:6:2e80:496:21b:63ff:fec6:70dd) DNS- Proxy-
5:31:43.990 PM UserEventAgent: Captive: CNPluginHandler en1: Inactive
5:31:44.012 PM netbiosd: network_reachability_changed : network is not reachable, netbiosd is shutting down
5:31:53.033 PM AirPlayUIAgent: 2014-09-02 05:31:53.033017 PM [AirPlayUIAgent] Changed PIN pairing: no
5:31:53.057 PM AirPlayUIAgent: 2014-09-02 05:31:53.056547 PM [AirPlayUIAgent] Changed PIN pairing: no
```

I then rebooted normally and actually had enough time to turn on WiFi manually (as occasionally happens).  Here are the logs from reboot and for another 10 seconds or so:

```
5:35:32.000 PM bootlog: BOOT_TIME 1409693732 0
5:35:34.000 PM syslogd: Configuration Notice:
ASL Module "com.apple.appstore" claims selected messages.
Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
5:35:34.000 PM syslogd: Configuration Notice:
ASL Module "com.apple.authd" sharing output destination "/var/log/system.log" with ASL Module "com.apple.asl".
Output parameters from ASL Module "com.apple.asl" override any specified in ASL Module "com.apple.authd".
5:35:34.000 PM syslogd: Configuration Notice:
ASL Module "com.apple.authd" claims selected messages.
Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
5:35:34.000 PM syslogd: Configuration Notice:
ASL Module "com.apple.bookstore" claims selected messages.
Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
5:35:34.000 PM syslogd: Configuration Notice:
ASL Module "com.apple.eventmonitor" claims selected messages.
Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
5:35:34.000 PM syslogd: Configuration Notice:
ASL Module "com.apple.install" claims selected messages.
Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
5:35:34.000 PM syslogd: Configuration Notice:
ASL Module "com.apple.iokit.power" claims selected messages.
Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
5:35:34.000 PM syslogd: Configuration Notice:
ASL Module "com.apple.mail" claims selected messages.
Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
5:35:34.000 PM syslogd: Configuration Notice:
ASL Module "com.apple.MessageTracer" claims selected messages.
Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
5:35:34.000 PM syslogd: Configuration Notice:
ASL Module "com.apple.performance" claims selected messages.
Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
5:35:34.000 PM syslogd: Configuration Notice:
ASL Module "com.apple.securityd" claims selected messages.
Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
5:35:34.000 PM syslogd: Configuration Notice:
ASL Module "com.apple.securityd" claims selected messages.
Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
5:35:34.000 PM syslogd: Configuration Notice:
ASL Module "com.apple.securityd" claims selected messages.
Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
5:35:34.000 PM syslogd: Configuration Notice:
ASL Module "com.apple.securityd" claims selected messages.
Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
5:35:34.000 PM syslogd: Configuration Notice:
ASL Module "com.apple.securityd" claims selected messages.
Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
5:35:34.000 PM syslogd: Configuration Notice:
ASL Module "com.apple.securityd" claims selected messages.
Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
5:35:34.000 PM syslogd: Configuration Notice:
ASL Module "com.apple.securityd" claims selected messages.
Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
5:35:34.000 PM kernel: Longterm timer threshold: 1000 ms
5:35:34.000 PM kernel: Darwin Kernel Version 13.3.0: Tue Jun  3 21:27:35 PDT 2014; root:xnu-2422.110.17~1/RELEASE_X86_64
5:35:34.000 PM kernel: vm_page_bootstrap: 988473 free pages and 51911 wired pages
5:35:34.000 PM kernel: kext submap [0xffffff7f807a9000 - 0xffffff8000000000], kernel text [0xffffff8000200000 - 0xffffff80007a9000]
5:35:34.000 PM kernel: zone leak detection enabled
5:35:34.000 PM kernel: "vm_compressor_mode" is 4
5:35:34.000 PM kernel: standard timeslicing quantum is 10000 us
5:35:34.000 PM kernel: standard background quantum is 2500 us
5:35:34.000 PM kernel: mig_table_max_displ = 74
5:35:34.000 PM kernel: Notice - new kext com.Logitech.Unifying.HID Driver, v1.3 matches prelinked kext but can't determine if executables are the same (no UUIDs).
5:35:34.000 PM kernel: Refusing new kext com.Logitech.Unifying.HID Driver, v1.3: already have prelinked v1.3.1.
5:35:34.000 PM kernel: AppleACPICPU: ProcessorId=0 LocalApicId=0 Enabled
5:35:34.000 PM kernel: AppleACPICPU: ProcessorId=1 LocalApicId=1 Enabled
5:35:34.000 PM kernel: calling mpo_policy_init for TMSafetyNet
5:35:34.000 PM kernel: Security policy loaded: Safety net for Time Machine (TMSafetyNet)
5:35:34.000 PM kernel: calling mpo_policy_init for Sandbox
5:35:34.000 PM kernel: Security policy loaded: Seatbelt sandbox policy (Sandbox)
5:35:34.000 PM kernel: calling mpo_policy_init for Quarantine
5:35:34.000 PM kernel: Security policy loaded: Quarantine policy (Quarantine)
5:35:34.000 PM kernel: Copyright (c) 1982, 1986, 1989, 1991, 1993
5:35:34.000 PM kernel: The Regents of the University of California. All rights reserved.
5:35:34.000 PM kernel: MAC Framework successfully initialized
5:35:34.000 PM kernel: using 16384 buffer headers and 10240 cluster IO buffer headers
5:35:34.000 PM kernel: AppleKeyStore starting (BUILT: Jun  3 2014 21:40:51)
5:35:34.000 PM kernel: IOAPIC: Version 0x20 Vectors 64:87
5:35:34.000 PM kernel: ACPI: sleep states S3 S4 S5
5:35:34.000 PM kernel: AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement: (built 21:36:10 Jun  3 2014) initialization complete
5:35:34.000 PM kernel: pci (build 21:30:51 Jun  3 2014), flags 0x63008, pfm64 (36 cpu) 0xf80000000, 0x80000000
5:35:34.000 PM kernel: [ PCI configuration begin ]
5:35:34.000 PM kernel: console relocated to 0xf80030000
5:35:34.000 PM kernel: [ PCI configuration end, bridges 7, devices 17 ]
5:35:34.000 PM kernel: ARPT cannot assert wake from D3cold
5:35:34.000 PM kernel: FireWire (OHCI) TI ID 8025 built-in now active, GUID 001d4ffffe75db34; max speed s800.
5:35:34.000 PM kernel: mcache: 2 CPU(s), 64 bytes CPU cache line size
5:35:34.000 PM kernel: mbinit: done [64 MB total pool size, (42/21) split]
5:35:34.000 PM kernel: Pthread support ABORTS when sync kernel primitives misused
5:35:34.000 PM kernel: rooting via boot-uuid from /chosen: EB767E62-D0E3-3E30-AEB4-2098C222FF25
5:35:34.000 PM kernel: Waiting on <dict ID="0"><key>IOProviderClass</key><string ID="1">IOResources</string><key>IOResourceMatch</key><string ID="2">boot-uuid-media</string></dict>
5:35:34.000 PM kernel: com.apple.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib kmod start
5:35:34.000 PM kernel: com.apple.AppleFSCompressionTypeLZVN kmod start
5:35:34.000 PM kernel: com.apple.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless kmod start
5:35:34.000 PM kernel: com.apple.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib load succeeded
5:35:34.000 PM kernel: com.apple.AppleFSCompressionTypeLZVN load succeeded
5:35:34.000 PM kernel: com.apple.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless load succeeded
5:35:34.000 PM kernel: AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient: ready
5:35:34.000 PM kernel: Got boot device = IOService:/AppleACPIPlatformExpert/PCI0/AppleACPIPCI/SATA@1F,2/AppleICH8AHCI/PRT0@0/IOAHCIDevice@0/AppleAHCIDiskDriver/IOAHCIBlockStorageDevice/IOBlockStorageDriver/Samsung SSD 840 EVO 250GB Media/IOGUIDPartitionScheme/Macintosh SSD@2
5:35:34.000 PM kernel: BSD root: disk0s2, major 1, minor 2
5:35:34.000 PM kernel: jnl: b(1, 2): replay_journal: from: 12825600 to: 16991744 (joffset 0x742000)
5:35:34.000 PM kernel: jnl: b(1, 2): journal replay done.
5:35:34.000 PM kernel: hfs: mounted Macintosh SSD on device root_device
5:35:34.000 PM kernel: No interval found for . Using 8000000
5:35:34.000 PM kernel: hfs: Removed 29 orphaned / unlinked files and 28 directories 
5:35:34.000 PM kernel: ath_get_caps[4044] rx chainmask mismatch actual 7 sc_chainmak 0
5:35:34.000 PM kernel: 2.384844: ath_get_caps[4019] tx chainmask mismatch actual 5 sc_chainmak 0
5:35:34.000 PM kernel: 2.387697: Atheros: mac 12.2 phy 8.1 radio 12.0
5:35:34.000 PM kernel: 2.387717: Use hw queue 0 for WME_AC_BE traffic
5:35:34.000 PM kernel: 2.387728: Use hw queue 1 for WME_AC_BK traffic
5:35:34.000 PM kernel: 2.387738: Use hw queue 2 for WME_AC_VI traffic
5:35:34.000 PM kernel: 2.387748: Use hw queue 3 for WME_AC_VO traffic
5:35:34.000 PM kernel: 2.387758: Use hw queue 8 for CAB traffic
5:35:34.000 PM kernel: 2.387767: Use hw queue 9 for beacons
5:35:34.000 PM kernel: 2.387922: wlan_vap_create : enter. devhandle=0x6f9e46b0, opmode=IEEE80211_M_STA, flags=0x1
5:35:34.000 PM kernel: 2.388006: wlan_vap_create : exit. devhandle=0x6f9e46b0, opmode=IEEE80211_M_STA, flags=0x1.
5:35:34.000 PM kernel: 2.388087: ATH tunables:
5:35:34.000 PM kernel: 2.388093:   pullmode[1] txringsize[  256] txsendqsize[1024] reapmin[   32] reapcount[  128]
5:35:34.000 PM kernel: No interval found for . Using 8000000
5:35:32.713 PM com.apple.launchd: *** launchd[1] has started up. ***
5:35:32.713 PM com.apple.launchd: *** Shutdown logging is enabled. ***
5:35:33.952 PM com.apple.SecurityServer: Session 100000 created
5:35:34.138 PM powerd: FIXME: IOUnserialize has detected a string that is not valid UTF-8, "?".
5:35:34.328 PM com.apple.SecurityServer: Entering service
5:35:34.332 PM powerd: FIXME: IOUnserialize has detected a string that is not valid UTF-8, "?".
5:35:34.000 PM kernel: IO80211Controller::dataLinkLayerAttachComplete():  adding AppleEFINVRAM notification
5:35:34.000 PM kernel: SMC::smcReadKeyAction ERROR: smcReadData8 failed for key $Num (kSMCKeyNotFound)
5:35:34.000 PM kernel: SMC::smcReadKeyAction ERROR $Num kSMCKeyNotFound(0x84) fKeyHashTable=0x0
5:35:34.000 PM kernel: SMC::smcReadKeyAction ERROR: smcReadData8 failed for key LsNM (kSMCKeyNotFound)
5:35:34.000 PM kernel: SMC::smcReadKeyAction ERROR LsNM kSMCKeyNotFound(0x84) fKeyHashTable=0x0
5:35:34.000 PM kernel: SMC::smcGetLightshowVers ERROR: smcReadKey LsNM failed (kSMCKeyNotFound)
5:35:34.000 PM kernel: SMC::smcPublishLightshowVersion ERROR: smcGetLightshowVers failed (kSMCKeyNotFound)
5:35:34.000 PM kernel: SMC::smcInitHelper ERROR: smcPublishLightshowVersion failed (kSMCKeyNotFound)
5:35:34.000 PM kernel: Previous Shutdown Cause: 3
5:35:34.000 PM kernel: SMC::smcInitHelper ERROR: MMIO regMap == NULL - fall back to old SMC mode
5:35:34.000 PM kernel: **** [IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport][start] -- completed -- result = TRUE -- 0x1800 ****
5:35:34.000 PM kernel: **** [CSRBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport][start] -- completed -- 0x1800 ****
5:35:34.000 PM kernel: init
5:35:34.000 PM kernel: probe
5:35:34.000 PM kernel: start
5:35:34.000 PM kernel: [IOBluetoothHCIController][staticBluetoothHCIControllerTransportShowsUp] -- Received Bluetooth Controller register service notification -- 0x1800 
5:35:34.000 PM kernel: [IOBluetoothHCIController][start] -- completed
5:35:34.000 PM kernel: NVDAStartup: Official
5:35:34.000 PM kernel: NVDANV50HAL loaded and registered
5:35:34.000 PM kernel: flow_divert_kctl_disconnect (0): disconnecting group 1
5:35:34.000 PM kernel: DSMOS has arrived
5:35:34.000 PM kernel: SMC::smcReadKeyAction ERROR: smcReadData8 failed for key ALRV (kSMCKeyNotFound)
5:35:34.000 PM kernel: AppleLMUController::smcReadKey received error 0x84 when reading key 'ALRV'.
5:35:34.697 PM UserEventAgent: Failed to copy info dictionary for bundle /System/Library/UserEventPlugins/alfUIplugin.plugin
5:35:34.716 PM UserEventAgent: Captive: CNPluginHandler en1: Inactive
5:35:34.000 PM kernel: AirPort: Link Down on en1. Reason 8 (Disassociated because station leaving).
5:35:34.723 PM configd: dhcp_arp_router: en1 SSID unavailable
5:35:34.000 PM kernel: [IOBluetoothHCIController::setConfigState] calling registerService
5:35:34.000 PM kernel: **** [IOBluetoothHCIController][protectedBluetoothHCIControllerTransportShowsUp] -- Connected to the transport successfully -- 0xb800 -- 0x2800 -- 0x1800 ****
5:35:34.757 PM configd: network changed.
5:35:34.758 PM configd: setting hostname to “*******-MacBook-Pro.local"
5:35:34.000 PM kernel: SMC::smcReadKeyAction ERROR: smcReadData8 failed for key MOTP (kSMCKeyNotFound)
5:35:34.000 PM kernel: SMC::smcReadKeyAction ERROR: smcReadData8 failed for key BEMB (kSMCKeyNotFound)
5:35:36.224 PM fseventsd: event logs in /.fseventsd out of sync with volume.  destroying old logs. (8604 4 8684)
5:35:36.226 PM fseventsd: log dir: /.fseventsd getting new uuid: 551A2EEC-5270-4C23-80C3-0F2085B4F542
5:35:38.000 PM kernel: AppleYukon2: Marvell Yukon Gigabit Adapter 88E8055 Singleport Copper SA
5:35:38.000 PM kernel: AppleYukon2: RxRingSize <= 1024, TxRingSize 256, RX_MAX_LE 1024, TX_MAX_LE 768, ST_MAX_LE 3328
5:35:39.120 PM hidd: void __IOHIDPlugInLoadBundles(): Loaded 0 HID plugins
5:35:39.121 PM hidd: Posting 'com.apple.iokit.hid.displayStatus' notifyState=1
5:35:39.000 PM kernel: VM Swap Subsystem is ON
5:35:39.412 PM mDNSResponder: mDNSResponder mDNSResponder-522.92.1 (Jun  3 2014 12:57:56) starting OSXVers 13
5:35:39.656 PM digest-service: label: default
5:35:39.656 PM digest-service:  dbname: od:/Local/Default
5:35:39.657 PM digest-service:  mkey_file: /var/db/krb5kdc/m-key
5:35:39.657 PM digest-service:  acl_file: /var/db/krb5kdc/kadmind.acl
5:35:39.660 PM digest-service: digest-request: uid=0
5:35:39.734 PM digest-service: digest-request: netr probe 0
5:35:39.735 PM digest-service: digest-request: init request
5:35:39.747 PM digest-service: digest-request: init return domain: BUILTIN server: DANIELS-MACBOOK-PRO indomain was: <NULL>
5:35:39.836 PM com.apple.usbmuxd: usbmuxd-327.4 on Feb 12 2014 at 14:54:33, running 64 bit
5:35:39.901 PM configd: network changed.
5:35:39.902 PM configd: network changed: DNS*
5:35:39.909 PM mDNSResponder: D2D_IPC: Loaded
5:35:39.909 PM mDNSResponder: D2DInitialize succeeded
5:35:39.914 PM mDNSResponder:   4: Listening for incoming Unix Domain Socket client requests
5:35:40.073 PM loginwindow: Login Window Application Started
5:35:40.000 PM kernel: [BNBTrackpadDevice::init][80.14] init is complete
5:35:40.154 PM networkd: networkd.111 built Aug 24 2013 22:08:46
5:35:40.166 PM apsd: CGSLookupServerRootPort: Failed to look up the port for "com.apple.windowserver.active" (1102)
5:35:40.000 PM kernel: [BNBTrackpadDevice::handleStart][80.14] returning 1
5:35:40.000 PM kernel: [AppleMultitouchHIDEventDriver::start] entered
5:35:40.000 PM kernel: No interval found for . Using 8000000
5:35:40.416 PM WindowServer: Server is starting up
5:35:40.433 PM WindowServer: Session 256 retained (2 references)
5:35:40.433 PM WindowServer: Session 256 released (1 references)
5:35:40.451 PM mds: (Normal) FMW: FMW 0 0
5:35:40.492 PM WindowServer: Session 256 retained (2 references)
5:35:40.000 PM kernel: [AppleMultitouchDevice::start] entered
5:35:40.529 PM WindowServer: init_page_flip: page flip mode is on
5:35:40.829 PM awacsd: Starting awacsd connectivity_executables-97 (Aug 24 2013 23:49:23)
5:35:40.836 PM awacsd: InnerStore CopyAllZones: no info in Dynamic Store
5:35:40.909 PM locationd: NBB-Could not get UDID for stable refill timing, falling back on random
5:35:40.945 PM locationd: Location icon should now be in state 'Inactive'
5:35:40.972 PM locationd: locationd was started after an unclean shutdown
5:35:41.017 PM systemkeychain: done file: /var/run/systemkeychaincheck.done
5:35:41.000 PM kernel: No interval found for . Using 8000000
5:35:41.000 PM kernel: No interval found for . Using 8000000
5:35:41.000 PM kernel: No interval found for . Using 8000000
5:35:41.000 PM kernel: No interval found for . Using 8000000
5:35:41.000 PM kernel: No interval found for . Using 8000000
5:35:41.000 PM kernel: No interval found for . Using 8000000
5:35:41.000 PM kernel: No interval found for . Using 8000000
5:35:41.000 PM kernel: No interval found for . Using 8000000
5:35:41.000 PM kernel: No interval found for . Using 8000000
5:35:41.000 PM kernel: No interval found for . Using 8000000
5:35:41.000 PM kernel: No interval found for . Using 8000000
5:35:41.000 PM kernel: No interval found for . Using 8000000
5:35:41.000 PM kernel: No interval found for . Using 8000000
5:35:41.000 PM kernel: No interval found for . Using 8000000
5:35:41.000 PM kernel: No interval found for . Using 8000000
5:35:41.000 PM kernel: No interval found for . Using 8000000
5:35:41.000 PM kernel: No interval found for . Using 8000000
5:35:41.000 PM kernel: No interval found for . Using 8000000
5:35:41.000 PM kernel: No interval found for . Using 8000000
5:35:41.000 PM kernel: No interval found for . Using 8000000
5:35:41.000 PM kernel: No interval found for . Using 8000000
5:35:41.000 PM kernel: No interval found for . Using 8000000
5:35:41.000 PM kernel: No interval found for . Using 8000000
5:35:41.000 PM kernel: No interval found for . Using 8000000
5:35:41.000 PM kernel: No interval found for . Using 8000000
5:35:41.162 PM airportd: airportdProcessDLILEvent: en1 attached (up)
5:35:41.000 PM kernel: 9.692484: setDISASSOC from ATH_INTERFACE_CLASS disconnectVap
5:35:41.000 PM kernel: 9.692499: switchVap from 1 to 1 
5:35:41.000 PM kernel: hfs: mounted Recovery HD on device disk0s3
5:35:41.502 PM mds: (Normal) Volume: volume:0x7fcfbb05be00 ********** Bootstrapped Creating a default store:0 SpotLoc:(null) SpotVerLoc:/Volumes/Recovery HD/.Spotlight-V100/Store-V1 occlude:0 /Volumes/Recovery HD
5:35:41.551 PM WindowServer: Found 42 modes for display 0x00000000 [42, 0]
5:35:41.567 PM fseventsd: Logging disabled completely for device:1: /Volumes/Recovery HD
5:35:41.582 PM WindowServer: Found 1 modes for display 0x00000000 [1, 0]
5:35:41.584 PM WindowServer: mux_initialize: Couldn't find any matches
5:35:41.000 PM kernel: hfs: unmount initiated on Recovery HD on device disk0s3
5:35:41.593 PM WindowServer: Found 42 modes for display 0x00000000 [42, 0]
5:35:41.599 PM WindowServer: Found 1 modes for display 0x00000000 [1, 0]
5:35:41.000 PM kernel: IOHIDSystem: Seize of com_Logitech_HIPointing failed.
5:35:41.000 PM kernel: IOHIDSystem: Seize of com_Logitech_HIPointing failed.
5:35:41.000 PM kernel: IOHIDSystem: Seize of com_Logitech_HIPointing failed.
5:35:41.000 PM kernel: IOHIDSystem: Seize of com_Logitech_HIPointing failed.
5:35:41.000 PM kernel: IOHIDSystem: Seize of Logitech HID Event Driver failed.
5:35:41.000 PM kernel: IOHIDSystem: Seize of IOHIDPointing failed.
5:35:41.000 PM kernel: IOHIDSystem: Seize of com_Logitech_HIPointing failed.
5:35:41.000 PM kernel: IOHIDSystem: Seize of com_Logitech_HIPointing failed.
5:35:41.000 PM kernel: IOHIDSystem: Seize of com_Logitech_HIPointing failed.
5:35:41.000 PM kernel: IOHIDSystem: Seize of com_Logitech_HIPointing failed.
5:35:41.000 PM kernel: IOHIDSystem: Seize of com_Logitech_HIPointing failed.
5:35:41.000 PM kernel: IOHIDSystem: Seize of com_Logitech_HIPointing failed.
5:35:41.000 PM kernel: IOHIDSystem: Seize of com_Logitech_HIPointing failed.
5:35:41.000 PM kernel: IOHIDSystem: Seize of com_Logitech_HIPointing failed.
5:35:41.000 PM kernel: IOHIDSystem: Seize of com_Logitech_HIPointing failed.
5:35:41.000 PM kernel: IOHIDSystem: Seize of com_Logitech_HIPointing failed.
5:35:41.000 PM kernel: IOHIDSystem: Seize of com_Logitech_HIPointing failed.
5:35:41.000 PM kernel: IOHIDSystem: Seize of com_Logitech_HIPointing failed.
5:35:41.000 PM kernel: IOHIDSystem: Seize of com_Logitech_HIPointing failed.
5:35:41.000 PM kernel: IOHIDSystem: Seize of com_Logitech_HIPointing failed.
5:35:41.000 PM kernel: IOHIDSystem: Seize of com_Logitech_HIPointing failed.
5:35:41.000 PM kernel: IOHIDSystem: Seize of com_Logitech_HIPointing failed.
5:35:41.000 PM kernel: IOHIDSystem: Seize of com_Logitech_HIPointing failed.
5:35:41.000 PM kernel: IOHIDSystem: Seize of com_Logitech_HIPointing failed.
5:35:41.000 PM kernel: IOHIDSystem: Seize of Logitech HID Event Driver failed.
5:35:41.000 PM kernel: IOHIDSystem: Seize of com_Logitech_HIPointing failed.
5:35:41.000 PM kernel: IOHIDSystem: Seize of com_Logitech_HIPointing failed.
5:35:41.687 PM WindowServer: WSMachineUsesNewStyleMirroring: false
5:35:41.688 PM WindowServer: Display 0x04271840: GL mask 0x1; bounds (0, 0)[1680 x 1050], 42 modes available
Main, Active, on-line, enabled, built-in, boot, Vendor 610, Model 9c61, S/N 0, Unit 0, Rotation 0
UUID 0x13300d27e6760312f098934f2d93447b
5:35:41.688 PM WindowServer: Display 0x003f003d: GL mask 0x2; bounds (0, 0)[0 x 0], 1 modes available
off-line, enabled, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 1, Rotation 0
UUID 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
5:35:41.691 PM WindowServer: WSSetWindowTransform: Singular matrix
5:35:41.697 PM WindowServer: Display 0x04271840: GL mask 0x1; bounds (0, 0)[1680 x 1050], 42 modes available
Main, Active, on-line, enabled, built-in, boot, Vendor 610, Model 9c61, S/N 0, Unit 0, Rotation 0
UUID 0x13300d27e6760312f098934f2d93447b
5:35:41.697 PM WindowServer: Display 0x003f003d: GL mask 0x2; bounds (2704, 0)[1 x 1], 1 modes available
off-line, enabled, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 1, Rotation 0
UUID 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
5:35:41.697 PM WindowServer: CGXPerformInitialDisplayConfiguration
5:35:41.697 PM WindowServer:   Display 0x04271840: Unit 0; Vendor 0x610 Model 0x9c61 S/N 0 Dimensions 14.45 x 9.06; online enabled built-in, Bounds (0,0)[1680 x 1050], Rotation 0, Resolution 1
5:35:41.697 PM WindowServer:   Display 0x003f003d: Unit 1; Vendor 0xffffffff Model 0xffffffff S/N -1 Dimensions 0.00 x 0.00; offline enabled, Bounds (2704,0)[1 x 1], Rotation 0, Resolution 1
5:35:41.759 PM WindowServer: GLCompositor: GL renderer id 0x01022604, GL mask 0x00000003, accelerator 0x00003677, unit 0, caps QEX|MIPMAP, vram 256 MB
5:35:41.769 PM WindowServer: GLCompositor: GL renderer id 0x01022604, GL mask 0x00000003, texture max 8192, viewport max {8192, 8192}, extensions FPRG|NPOT|GLSL|FLOAT
5:35:41.770 PM WindowServer: GLCompositor enabled for tile size [256 x 256]
5:35:41.770 PM WindowServer: CGXGLInitMipMap: mip map mode is on
5:35:41.787 PM loginwindow: **DMPROXY** Found `/System/Library/CoreServices/DMProxy'.
5:35:41.932 PM WindowServer: Display 0x04271840: Unit 0; ColorProfile { 2, "Color LCD"}; TransferTable (256, 12)
5:35:42.063 PM launchctl: com.apple.findmymacmessenger: Already loaded
5:35:42.261 PM loginwindow: Setting the initial value of the magsave brightness level 1
5:35:42.315 PM loginwindow: Login Window Started Security Agent
5:35:42.561 PM SecurityAgent: This is the first run
5:35:42.561 PM SecurityAgent: MacBuddy was run = 0
5:35:42.584 PM WindowServer: _CGXGLDisplayContextForDisplayDevice: acquired display context (0x7fc51b506ff0) - enabling OpenGL
5:35:42.666 PM SecurityAgent: User info context values set for *******
5:35:42.785 PM com.apple.SecurityServer: Session 100004 created
5:35:43.242 PM UserEventAgent: Failed to copy info dictionary for bundle /System/Library/UserEventPlugins/alfUIplugin.plugin
5:35:43.284 PM loginwindow: Login Window - Returned from Security Agent
5:35:43.342 PM loginwindow: USER_PROCESS: 66 console
5:35:43.000 PM kernel: AppleKeyStore:Sending lock change 0
5:35:43.579 PM com.apple.launchd.peruser.501: Background: Aqua: Registering new GUI session.
5:35:43.623 PM com.apple.launchd.peruser.501: (com.apple.EscrowSecurityAlert) Unknown key: seatbelt-profiles
5:35:43.624 PM com.apple.launchd.peruser.501: (com.apple.ReportCrash) Falling back to default Mach exception handler. Could not find: com.apple.ReportCrash.Self
5:35:43.629 PM launchctl: com.apple.pluginkit.pkd: Already loaded
5:35:43.630 PM launchctl: com.apple.sbd: Already loaded
5:35:43.692 PM WindowServer: **DMPROXY** (2) Found `/System/Library/CoreServices/DMProxy'.
5:35:43.716 PM distnoted: # distnote server agent  absolute time: 12.200075348   civil time: Tue Sep  2 17:35:43 2014   pid: 147 uid: 501  root: no
```

Unfortunately there were no logs right around the time the computer froze (5:33).

Comment: In order to evalute the root cause we need to see your Console report at the time of interest (when you turn off your wifi and some 50 lines after that. Since your computer will freeze, once you have it going scroll back in the Console to the time of the event.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion to use Console, @Buscar웃. I've updated my question with Console logs encompassing the time of the freeze.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what do you use the Netbios (Network Basic Input/Output System) for ?

Comment: I see the netbios reference in the first set of logs (from before the freeze) but I don't know what it's used for.  I think it was just one of the cascade of log messages that came shortly after turning off WiFi.

Comment: Are you connecting to Windows server or any servers at all, or company networks?

Comment: In the past two weeks, since switching to Mavericks, I have started to experience the same, or very similar, issue. I turn off wifi and the Santa Rosa MBP (2.4MHz) locks up. I was using Mountain Lion, which did not show the same issue. I do not have the same SMC issues, which are shown in your logs. I shall compare logs further, to see if I can track down the cause of the issue. However, at the time of switching off the wifi, just before the (forced) reboot, I see no untoward messages or errors in the log.

Answer (score 1):

I've got a band-aid solution to this now.  Basically I wrote a bash script to check the WiFi status and turn it on if it's off.  I then wrote two plist files for calling the script with launchd: one plist is a daemon and it calls the script right at boot, the other is an agent and it calls the script whenever the following file is modified: /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/preferences.plist.  That's the file that the OS stores the WiFi status in.

I put all my code up on GitHub and made a simple installer:

https://github.com/dmuenz/KeepWiFiOn

I've only tested this on my own computer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the Console log. I can only imagine how stressed you were to get it all done before shut down happened :)

Lets start with the obvious first (the rest comes later)

You have many SMC (system management controller) Errors.

Reset your SMC using the [procedure from Apple](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3964).